# Mystery of the wet internal door

Tags: wood, moisture

I have a mystery and would like help solving it. I have an old original Victorian door in my house that gets a wet patch on it. It’s permanently wet / damp in the same area, although sometimes the dampness gets larger.

It only happens to two doors. There is no damp around it (ceiling, floor etc). It isn’t near a bathroom and the bathroom door (which is the same) doesn’t have this issue. No other area of the door seems to get it.

My only guess is, does it have wood worm or something inside, that might been creating moisture in the door? Could it be the old adhesive in the door breaking down?! [image][image]

Comment: I can’t tell where the issue is from the photo is there some kind of metal , like a welcome sign or house numbers on the door that could make a cold spot?

Comment: Suggestions for better photos: 1) most important, make sure it's _in focus_; 2) make sure it's well-lit; 3) provide context, by showing a wide view, along with a close-up of the area in question that seems problematic; 4) state clearly what it is in the photo that you're asking about. I see a lot of irregularity in the appearance of the wood in your photo, but nothing that jumps out at me as clearly "wet". And without context, it'd be impossible to know why it's wet. For all we know, the door is floating in a backyard pool.

Comment: Sometimes the dampness gets larger. What times?

Comment: i do not see a damp spot in the picture

Comment: I’ve added another picture now

Comment: What makes you think it is wet?  Is it the fact it is darker?  Is there moisture beading on the surface?

Comment: Because it feels damp to the touch

Comment: There is no metal on the other side of the door. It’s plain both sides. I’m not sure the kind of time I would have to check for that.

Comment: Those pictures look like they are of totally different doors. The wood color is totally different (could be lighting, I suppose), there are knots in the top picture that aren't there in the bottom one (other side of the door? the knots would still show, even if they were different sizes), the amount and texture of the grain appear to be different. Is the bottom picture supposed to be portrait but got rotated on posting to a landscape orientation? If so, which way is up?

Comment: At what time of the day, week, month, year does the dampness seem to increase? Is it regular or just occasionally?  You've generated a fair bit of interest in your issue, but we need more info to help you solve the mystery

Comment: Where is the door located, and are there ever any noticeable drafts at or near the location?

Comment: It actually occurred on two doors in the house, both pictures are there in the photos. One is on the west side of house in middle floor in bathroom (just a toilet) and other is on the top floor on opposite side of house for bedroom. It’s wet 24/7. Not sure when it increases, it’s pretty stable to be honest, if it does increase it’s not by a lot.